# Export data from dynamic website with BS4 + Python:

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to export all store data from the following website into a excel-file:
https://www.ybpn.de/ihre-parfuemerien

The problem: The Map is "dynamic", so the needed data loads when you enter a postal code.

The data is need is stored in the div-class "storefinder__list-item" with a unique reference in the data-"storefinder-reference" div-class, example: data-storefinder-reference="132"

I tried:

```
soup.find("div", {"data-storefinder-reference": "132"})
```

But the output is: *NONE*

I think this problem is caused by the fact that the page is dynamic, so the needed data loads then, when you enter a postal code. So when I search for the reference id "132" its "there", but not loaded on the website and bs4 cant find this id.

Any ideas to improve the code?

Comment: I think you can just use requests. Can you share an example of zip code and data you expect to get?

Comment: ZIP Code: 10365 and then I get 5 "storefinder__list-item storefinder__list-item--active" div-classes, in every div-class are the subclasses for the data I need, example: storefinder-item__title or storefinder-item__adress. But the problem is that the page only loads 5 results, there are over 1000 - and I need the full list :/

Comment: Your task is called `web-scraping`. Therefore, I highly recommend using Scrapy to achieve this. Basically, [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) works similarly to BS4 + Python requests, but more robust and mature. If you need to handle dynamic elements, [Scrapy-Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) will help you as well. Check this [Scrapy-Splash Introduction](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash)

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I actually got some problems with bs4 + selenium. Maybe its better to try your way.

Answer (score 1):

For this you might need to look into tools like [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and/or "firefox-headless".

Especially selenium allows you to "remote-control" web-pages with Python

Here is a tutorial: https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/

Comment: So I have to "simulate" the user action "enter postal code" with selenium - maybe based on a text file with all postal codes for germany to do this automatically?

Comment: Yes. That would be the way to do it.

Comment: But when I use selenium, maybe the website / ddos protection block the action if they notice that it is not "human", or? Use the "sleep"-command? I think we got a lot of postal codes for whole germany, so the script have to do many actions to get the full list.

Comment: This is a possibility, but unlikely. To be on the safe side, you can add sleeps with random delays into each call. But more importantly is the "user-agent" request header. When you do the request in chrome/firefox you will see the value in the request-headers. Just copy/paste that value and add it to your application as request header. That will make it "look" human.

Comment: The sounds like a good way. Ill try it with selenium and the sleep/user-agent. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is waiting for the page to load, you can do it with selenium.

```
`result = driver.execute_script('var text = document.title ; return text')`
```

If there is jquery on the page, it certainly does

```
result=driver.execute_script("""
       $(document).ready({
          var $text=$('yourselector').text()
           return $text
           })
          """)
```

> Note: For selenium you can look [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

Comment: Yeah, I think that I have to try it with selenium. I dont know if they use jquery. :/

Answer (score 0):

You could just open the page in chrome or ff, open the web debug console and query the elements. if you see them they are in the dom and thus queryable. But that will be done in javascript. if you‘re lucky they use jQuery.

Comment: yeah, I did this. But there are only some "items", no the whole list. In the "storefinder__info"-class there is a string with the information: "12 results". I think they use javascript, how to find out if they use jquery?

Comment: i guess there are ajax requests paging through the list items. you can also see those in the requests tab of the dev tools. maybe they send a parameter defining the number or results. anyway you can request all that manually too.